# send mail with attachment body

Tags: xamarin.android

Use this code to send an email to me and work with me.
What I want now is to send a file attachment also with the message.

```
  var email = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraEmail, new string[] {
            "susairajs@outlook.com",
            "susairajs18@gmail.com"
        });
            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraCc, new string[] {
            "susairajs18@live.com"
        });
            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, "Hello Xamarin");
            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText, "Hello Xamarin This is My Test Mail...!");
            email.SetType("message/rfc822");
            StartActivity(email);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample.txt in Assets folder. Set the Build Action to AndroidAsset.

[image]

The Path of the txt file.

```
//android_asset/sample.txt
```

Usage:

```
btnSend.Click += delegate
        {
            Android.Net.Uri file = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new 
Java.IO.File("//android_asset/sample.txt"));
            var email = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraEmail,
            new string[] { "xxxxxx@xxxxx.com" });
            //email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraCc,
            //new string[] { "something@gmail.com" });
            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, "Awesome File");
            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText, "See attached file");
            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraStream, file);
            email.SetType("message/rfc822");
            StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(email, "Send email..."));
        };
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it would be something like this:

```
        string filename = "file.ext";
        var filelocation = new File(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, filename);
        Uri path = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(filelocation);
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
        emailIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, path);
```

with the following using statements:

```
using File = Java.IO.File;
using Uri = Android.Net.Uri;
```

Comment: hi FreakyAli  code get error The file could not be sent

Comment: What type of file do you have? And what is the size?

Comment: text file size 18.6 KB

Comment: Do one thing share your latest code as an update to your question, Also make sure that the path that you are referring in the code and the path that your file is in are the same!

Comment: II added the file to the Assest path